# Interview - Size of an Integer

Tags: types, computer-science, primitive-types

I just just had a phone interview and they asked me this question:

"What is the size of an integer, and, what is the equation to work this out?"

I had no idea (Ok, I'm a bit stupid) but it just intrigues me to find out the answer. My person guess was count up in base 2.. But I dunno.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It entirely depends. The question is not well-posed. Were they asking about a specific data type in a specific language? How many bits it takes to represent some decimal number? Something else?

Comment: @MattBall Just the size of an Integer, that is all they asked. I was confused to hell!

Comment: Then you should have asked for clarification, because there is no correct answer to a question this vague.

Comment: The probably wanted you to ask for clarification. They probably phrased the question vaguely to see if you could hunt down exactly what they were after. Also they probably wanted to see what you know about standard int sizes in various systems, and the min size to store an int of a certain range. ( `log_2(MAX_VALUE)` ) for unisgned int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the question was asked to make you ask them:

- What is the largest value that you want the `integer` type to encode?

Let's assume they said we want `MAX_VALUE` to be the maximum value an integer type can have.

This brings us to the equation. Since we are encoding it using bits we need `log_2(MAX_VALUE)` bits to encode any positive value of size up to `MAX_VALUE`. The logarithm of base 2 is there because with a bit pattern of size `n` you can encode up to `2^n` different values. So if you want to know how long your maximum bit pattern needs to be to encode `MAX_VALUE` you need to calculate the `log` since:

```
2^(log_2(MAX_VALUE)) = MAX_VALUE
```

Now this is okay, unless you also want to encode the number 0. If you want to encode 0 as well then there are MAX_VALUE+1 numbers between 0 and MAX_VALUE so you need `log_2(MAX_VALUE+1)` bits to encode them all.

Another important question is what is the `MIN_VALUE` that we want to encode?

So in total you have `MAX_VALUE + 1 + abs(MIN_VALUE)` different values, so you will need :

```
bits_needed = log_2(MAX_VALUE + 1 + abs(MIN_VALUE))
```

As others have mentioned, in java `int` has `max_value = 2,147,483,647` and `min_value = -2,147,483,648`. When you do the calculation you get `log_2(4294967296)` which is equal to 32. So 32 bits is the size of the integer type in java.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, are you looking for integer bit-size for different programming languages? or you want to know the MAX value of int.

BTW, in java int is 32 bits and max is 2^31-1=2,147,483,647

Answer (score 0):

I think he asked for the range of integer.
in Java, the size is 4 bytes, so should range from -2^31 to 2^31-1?
Since he asked for the equation.